# Script won't replace empty space with gsub

Tags: lua

I have a lua script that gives me an errors trying to replace an empty space with %20

```
text = "This is great"
text = string.lower(text)

output = text:gsub("%s", "%20")
print(output)
```

I want this to replace the empty space in this with %20 but it gives an error

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message.

Answer (score 2):

The percent sign has special meaning not only in the gsub's search pattern, but in the replacement pattern as well. More specifically, `%2` means “the content of the pattern's second capture group”. If you escape percent sign with another percent sign, it loses its special meaning:

```
output = text:gsub("%s", "%%20")
```

*However...*
It seems like you're trying to make your string a part of an URL. URLencode/URLdecode is more than just replacing spaces with `%20`, it's a rather involving transformation described in details by [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). It's worth using a thirdparty library for that.

Comment: This script is for Roblox and they have a pre-built API for URL Encode which will works perfectly for this scenario, thanks

Comment: @iHaxtedU: If you're happy with the answer, it may be a good idea to mark the question as resolved.